# AJAX is coming back in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

Okay, so I am writing a little chat system for a project I'm working on. I've been trying to learn AJAX in the process, and all seems to be going well. My AJAX runs a PHP page that opens a directory, and AJAX receives the directory back from the page as an Array (DirectoryList). It then loads another AJAX function over and over until all of the chat logs are appended to the DIV.

My problem is that the ChatLogs are not loaded in the right order.

For example, if I had the Logs:

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- 3.txt
- 4.txt

They would be appended to the ChatContainer DIV as:

- 2.txt
- 1.txt
- 4.txt
- 3.txt

Instead of the correct order.

Here's my code:

```
var ChatList = new Array();
var p;
var DirectoryList = new Array();
var ChatString = '';

function loadChat(variable) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            DirectoryList = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            var p = variable;
            while (p < DirectoryList.length) {
                loadLog(p);
                p++;
            }
        }
    }

    //END REQ1

    //Post Chat to DIV

    function loadLog(p) {
        $.get('chat/log/' + DirectoryList[p], function (data2) {
            ChatList.push(data2);
            $('#ChatContainer').append(data2);
        });
    }

    //End
    req.open('GET', 'process/ReadChatLogs.php', true)
    req.send(null);
}

loadChat(0);
```

Comment: The "A" in AJAX is stands for asynchronous. Responses are not required to have an order.

Comment: Ajax is not guaranteed to finish in the same order that you request them because the server may take longer to return one request than it does the next. to solve this, wait until they are all done, then loop over the original collection and append the results.

Comment: You propably will have to implement a solution using [**jQuery.deferred**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Comment: Why are you mixing the use of `jQuery.get` and `XMLHttpRequest`? Just wondering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ajax is not guaranteed to finish in the same order that you request them because the server may take longer to return one request than it does the next. to solve this, wait until they are all done, then loop over the original collection and append the results. Below is how you could do that with deferred objects.

```
var ChatList = new Array();
var p;
var DirectoryList = new Array();
var ChatString = '';

function loadChat(variable) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            DirectoryList = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            var p = variable;
            var defArr = []; // store references to deferred objects
            while (p < DirectoryList.length) {
                defArr.push(loadLog(p));
                p++;
            }
            $.when.apply($,defArr).done(function(){ // apply handler when all are done
                // handle case where only one ajax request was sent
                var args = arguments;
                if ($.type(args[0]) != "array") {
                    args = [];
                    args[0] = arguments;
                }
                // loop over and ouput results.
                var outHTML = "";
                $.each(args,function(i){
                    outHTML += args[i][0];
                    ChatList.push(args[i][0]);
                });
                $("#ChatContainer").append(outHTML);
            });
        }
    }

    //END REQ1

    //Post Chat to DIV

    function loadLog(p) {
        return $.get('chat/log/' + DirectoryList[p]);
    }

    //End
    req.open('GET', 'process/ReadChatLogs.php', true)
    req.send(null);
}
```

Edit: fixed case where only one ajax request is sent

Comment: +1 for example. In addition you also just improved performance as you only write ones to the DOM in the end instead of each time during the loop. Nice.

Comment: Why do you use `$.when.apply($,defArr)...` rather than just `$.when(defArr)...`?